Does a file extension for a base-16 dump exist? If so, what is it?
Rationale

If I want to attach this to a Bugzilla ticket (like this attachment) the best way is as a file. However, I'd rather use a file extension which means that the IDE is able to:

Provide proper syntax highlighting.
Automatically disable word wrapping.

Of course, I could upload a basic Markdown file with the dump encapsulated in a fenced code block (or HTML5 <pre>s). However, not everyone has a Markdown or HTML renderer in their IDE.
Example

As an example, consider the undermentioned (from this GitHub discussion comment):
00000000: 3010 1203 0400 2062 0000 0000 b212 0d00  0..... b........
00000010: 0000 0000 6501 f203 7aaf 0000 0000 c837  ....e...z......7
00000020: c837 c837 906f 80bb 3075 2701 a000 8200  .7.7.o..0u'.....
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 d400 0000 d400 0000 d400  ................
00000040: 0000 d400 0000 8813 0888 1308 204e 2010  ............ N .
00000050: 2710 1534 2010 2710 c409 044c 1d0c 0000  '..4 .'....L....
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 1000 8632 8015 8a8c 8213 0000 0000 0000  ...2............
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0f11 0171 0822 0000 0000  .........q."....
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 a14d  ...............M
00000200: 0198 0823 328e 0a9b e84b 4635 3536 5334  ...#2....KF556S4
00000210: 302d 3332 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  0-32            
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2000 80ad 4100 0831 3030         ...A..100
00000230: 3139 3738 3700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  19787...........
00000240: 0000 4100 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000  ..A.............
00000250: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000260: 0000 0001 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0088  ................
00000270: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000280: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000290: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000300: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000320: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000330: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000340: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000350: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000360: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000370: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000380: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000390: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................


There is likely no "standard" file extension. I've seen .hex or .dump in the past but what the IDE editor chooses to do with any file is going to depend entirely on the IDE, which you have not mentioned.

Maybe .bin, but as Mokubai points out, a file extension really says nothing, its up to the IDE.

In my experience Linux could not care less about what extension a file has, the only file extensions became important on Windows, is due to Windows allow you to configure what application to open a file extension with by double clicking on it. This information was stored in the registry hive.

@LPChip, isn't .bin used for binary files? This is a textual representation of a binary file (albeit in fairly standard layout).

@Ramhound, I'm aware. That's why I've asked - many of my colleagues use Windows, and certain cross-platform IDEs that they use tend to prefer file extensions. I'd rather not ignore their situation, even if for us, Linux-based OSes do it better.

@Mokuba, I'm hoping to write a syntax highlighting extension for VS Code if the functionality doesn't exist. However, I needed a starting point to ensure that I didn't duplicate existent work, and that I would be able to correlate the extension to a specific file extension in its manifest for Windows users. Thanks for the examples - those do have some hits on Google. Would you add them as an answer?

Yes it is, it might help you to ensure that VS code won't do any syntax hilighting for it, as .bin doesn't really have a syntax.

@LPChip, unfortunately, that IDE seems to be intelligent enough to test whether the file actually has non-UFT8 content inside, and solely apply what I want if it does. Thanks, though. This is reason enough to find a standard extension that I can use so that I can correct this behaviour.

For submission, .md would be the proper way.

@JayCravens, I agree. Thanks.

According to comments on the question, it appears not. I've been unable to locate any file extensions utilized for this purpose, even solely in a specific context.
Instead, the next best is to format the file using a plain-text-readable markup language that supports disabling line breaks for arbitrary text blocks, like Markdown does. As an example, see the undermentioned:
```hexdump
00000000: 3010 1203 0400 2062 0000 0000 b212 0d00  0..... b........
00000010: 0000 0000 6501 f203 7aaf 0000 0000 c837  ....e...z......7
00000020: c837 c837 906f 80bb 3075 2701 a000 8200  .7.7.o..0u'.....
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 d400 0000 d400 0000 d400  ................
00000040: 0000 d400 0000 8813 0888 1308 204e 2010  ............ N .
00000050: 2710 1534 2010 2710 c409 044c 1d0c 0000  '..4 .'....L....
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 1000 8632 8015 8a8c 8213 0000 0000 0000  ...2............
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0f11 0171 0822 0000 0000  .........q."....
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 a14d  ...............M
00000200: 0198 0823 328e 0a9b e84b 4635 3536 5334  ...#2....KF556S4
00000210: 302d 3332 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  0-32            
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2000 80ad 4100 0831 3030         ...A..100
00000230: 3139 3738 3700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  19787...........
00000240: 0000 4100 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000  ..A.............
00000250: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000260: 0000 0001 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0088  ................
00000270: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000280: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000290: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000300: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000320: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000330: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000340: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000350: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000360: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000370: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000380: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000390: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

This certainly functions for my purposes.
